# iterator header: can't use begin or end with array as argument, c++11

Tags: arrays, pointers, iterator

1>c:\users\indira\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cpppremier\cpppremier\ch1.cpp(2060): error C3861: 'begin': identifier not found

1>c:\users\indira\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cpppremier\cpppremier\ch1.cpp(2060): error C3861: 'end': identifier not found

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include<array>
#include<vector>
#include <iterator>
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int ia[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    int *pbeg = begin(ia),  *pend = end(ia);

    cout << "Elements in arr: " << endl;

   for (int *pbeg; pbeg != pend; ++pbeg)
    { 
        *pbeg = 0;
        cout << *pbeg << endl;
    }


    getchar();
    getchar();

return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this is not working.I'm trying to use the iterator header to use begin and end functions defined in that header.
The code has the iterator header. The functions are taking the array as argument, since array is not a class type...
I tried this in visual studio 2013, and in compileonline.com c++11.

Answer (score 0):

`begin` and `end` are functions in the `std` namespace, so  you should introduce them with `using`, or qualify them (eg. as `std::begin`).

You don't need this when your argument is itself a `std` type: argument-dependent lookup finds them in that case - but ADL doesn't work when your arguments are primitive types, or anything else not itself defined inside `namespace std`.

---

Here's some sample code to explain how name lookup works in this case.  Just because something is visible in a translation unit, doesn't mean it's a valid match.

```
namespace test {
    struct Type { };

    void foo(Type);
    void bar(int);
}

int main() {
    /*
    Type t; <-- NO: Type is declared but not visible for name lookup
        nl.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
        nl.cpp:11:5: error: ‘Type’ was not declared in this scope
        nl.cpp:11:5: note: suggested alternative:
        nl.cpp:3:12: note:   ‘test::Type’
    */

    test::Type u; // OK: the qualified name can be looked up
    foo(u);       // OK: argument-dependent lookup means test is considered

    /*
    bar(1); <--  NO: int isn't part of namespace test
        nl.cpp:22:10: error: ‘bar’ was not declared in this scope
        nl.cpp:22:10: note: suggested alternative:
        nl.cpp:6:10: note:   ‘test::bar’
    */

    test::bar(1); // OK: explicitly tell the compiler where to look
}
```

You can either introduce names from a different namespace into your current one with `using` (you already did this with `std::string` etc.), or explicitly qualify them.

Comment: begin and end functions are defined in iterator header. it should work w/o the std::begin. if i change the code to that still doesn't work:    int *pbeg = std::begin(ia) is "used without being initialized".

Comment: They're defined in the header _in the std namespace_. Note that with your change, you got a _different_ error, and I suspect it's in the for loop, where you declared a new, uninitialized `pbeg` variable, which hides the existing one.

Comment: By correcting the uninitialized problem, the code works (using your suggestion i can also erase the #include<iterator>, cause is accessing it from the std namespace.). But i still don't understand why the iterator header is not working. Here is a link where it shows that these functions are defined in this header.So the original question still troubles me: using the iterator header.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3tf6509.aspx